# opening a new window onload and transfer text HTML

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I have to open a new window from a parent window and transfer text to the new window. I am able to do it if the new window opens in a separate tab and the current window is not closed. If I try to use "_self" and open the new window in the parent window page, my text is not transferred to the new, since the statements below window.open are not executed. Please help me fix this.

```
popupWin = window.open("/c1.html",'_self'); 
popupWin.onload = function() { 
    popupTextContent = popupWin.document.getElementById("a1"); 
    parentTextContent = document.getElementById("a2"); 
    popupTextTitle = popupWin.document.getElementById("a3"); 
    parentTextTitle = document.getElementById("a4"); 
    transferText(); 
} 

function transferText() { 
    .............//code to transfer text.... 
}
```

Comment: Generally, one would POST the data to the new window -- how are you doing it? Please show code.

Comment: popupWin = window.open("/c1.html",'_self');

  popupWin.onload = function() {
   popupTextContent = popupWin.document.getElementById("a1");
   parentTextContent = document.getElementById("a2");
   popupTextTitle = popupWin.document.getElementById("a3");
   parentTextTitle = document.getElementById("a4");
   transferText();
    }

function transferText()
  {
 .............//code to transfer text....
  }

Comment: Please put your code inside the question.